# Mongo DB query in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

How to use regex match with array operators in Spring boot?

I need to perform regex match (partial match) in field named as keyword which is of type List.

Code needs to written in Spring Boot.

For Simple string field I have successfully performed regex match using String Operators.

I tried using String Operators but it gives error saying input value needs to be string but keyword (field for which I need to perform regex) is of type List.
I think we need to iterate through array and then use string operator but not sure how to achieve it.